# Can I say 'to a society be correct, it needs coordination'?

Tags: phrase-usage

Does the following sentence sound correct?

> To a society be correct, it needs coordination.

If it is not correct, what is the correct way to say that?

Comment: It is not correct, and while the answer is a possible interpretation, it is not at all clear what you mean.  In general, requests to correct the grammar in an expression are often closed as "proofreading".

Answer (score -1):

> To be a correct society, it needs coordination.

or

> For a society to be correct, it needs coordination.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your answer. I think the answer could be greatly improved by adding some explanation. The second sentence you suggested is definitely better, but why? Your first suggestion suffers in that "society" is not the subject and doesn't connect naturally with "it."

Comment: A more natural version of the first sentence: *To be correct, a society needs coordination.*